# GCE custom domain for Magento 2

Tags: domain

I have created an **A record** to point my domain name to my google compute engine static IP.

I have also updated my `core_config_data` table with my domain name, but when trying to browse to the domain name, it redirects to the IP address instead.

I disabled cache and have cleared it several times.

I can't figure out what I'm missing. I have reviewed the documentation for the app engine and it does not appear to apply to compute engine. Any help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to magento.stackexchange.com! Did you try to replace the standard Magento 2 `index.php` with a test/demo `index.php` where you just put in a `die('M2')` statement? This would help identifying if the redirect comes from Magento (which I don't think) or from your Google compute/app engine configuration.

Answer (score 1):

actually just found my issue. I assume it was an apache issue... I launched the stack through bitnami and they have a configuration script that you run from the application directory:

cd /opt/bitnami/apps/magento

sudo ./bnconfig --machine_hostname my-blog.com

Comment: Nice! Don't forget to accept your own answer 48 hours after posting so that it is marked as resolved :-)